# Similar looking UTF8 characters for ASCII

Tags: utf-8, ascii, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

I'm looking for a table which contains ASCII characters and same looking UTF8 characters. I know it also depends on the font is they look the same, but something generic to start with is enough.

```
>>> # PY3 code:
>>> a='H'  # ascii
>>> b='Н'  # utf8
>>> a==b
False
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in a)
'1001000'
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in b)
'10000011101'
>>> a='P'  # ascii
>>> b='Ρ'  # utf8
>>> a==b
False
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in a)
'1010000'
>>> ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in b)
'1110100001'
```

Comment: "UTF-8 characters" are simply [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters (codepoints, to be precise), as UTF-8 is just an encoding for Unicode. So you are looking for a way to find Unicode codepoints that look similar to ASCII characters?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Sorry if that was not obvious.

Comment: Similar question on security.SE: [List of visually similar characters, for detecting spoofing and social engineering attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128286/list-of-visually-similar-characters-for-detecting-spoofing-and-social-engineeri/128465).

Comment: Yes, but I'm not looking for "lol" ~ "lo1".

Comment: You've got some terminology issues. Your question is equally valid to any system that uses Unicode, not just those that store strings using its UTF-8 encoding. All the characters you are using are Unicode. By ASCII, you seem to mean [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). UTF-8 is not considered extended ASCII. Also, your `for x in a` iterates over Unicode codepoints, not UTF-8 code units. (`==` does compare the sequences of UTF-8 code units.)

Answer (score 13):

This is very useful tool as it will show you all characters which look similar and you can choose if this is REALLY similar enough for you :)

https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=test&r=None

Some other resources:

- This is called [Visual Spoofing](http://websec.github.io/unicode-security-guide/visual-spoofing/)
- [Python Package to detect confusables](https://pypi.org/project/confusables/)